# Zonal Statistics-Weighting

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster file on precipitation and I want to create zonal statistics as a table using a shapefile with boundaries of countries across the world. However it appears that I need to take into account that in different latitudes the  corresponding area is different and thus I need to weight my statistic (mean etc.) for area.

Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: I should clarify that I work with ARCGIS 10.1

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly: use an equal-area projection. Then you do not have to "weight you statistic".

Comment: An_Li, @Jens offers the best solution: use an equal-area projection.  However, if you wish to avoid reprojecting (and the resampling that necessarily goes along with that), your idea is quite workable.  At the very end of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53664/sum-raster-data-visible-from-given-point-by-proportion-of-view/54002#54002, I describe how to obtain a weighted (zonal) average.  For weights, use the cosine of the latitude.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open for other GIS tools then have a look at SAGA-GIS:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/

There is a module called "Grid Statistics for Polygons" which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try the equal area projection. Unfortunately I am new to ARC GIS so I already have difficulties with already, let alone moving to a different software.